# How to set datagridview cell format when editing and after editing in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

The format of my `DataGridView` is correct when it is loaded. But when I try to edit the value and accepts it (enter or tab), the format is not applied.

I have added this `CellEndEdit` event hoping that it will correct the format after editing.

```
private void dataGridSales_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridSales.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
    }
}

private void dataGridSales_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
        dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";

    }
}
```

or

```
private void dataGridSales_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
}
```

But instead it still doesn't show the correct format.

Cell value before editing:
[image: Cell value before editing]

Cell in edit mode:
[image: Cell in edit mode]

How can I change the format to `N2` or to remove the currency sign when editing? You can see my `CellBeginEdit` event above, it changes the whole column format to `N2`. I want to change only the selected cell.

Cell value after editing:
[image: Cell value after editing]

Column Default Cell Style:
[image: Column Default Cell Style]

dataGridSales Events Code:

```
    //Change Total Amount when Price Column is changed
    private void dataGridSales_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridSales.Rows)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
        }
        lblTotAmt.Text = "Total Amount: " + total.ToString("C2");
        lblTotItem.Text = "Total Items: " + count;
    }
    //Remove item/s
    private void dataGridSales_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridSales.Rows)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
        }
        lblTotAmt.Text = "Total Amount: " + total.ToString("C2");
        lblTotItem.Text = "Total Items: " + count;
    }
    //Price Column check
    private void dataGridSales_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(colPrice_KeyPress);
        //e.Control.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(dataGridSales_KeyDown);
        if (dataGridSales.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(colPrice_KeyPress);
            }
            if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                cprice = e.Control as TextBox;
            }
        }
    }
    //Price Column keypress only accept numbers
    private void colPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        TextBox txtDec = sender as TextBox;
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtDec.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridSales_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridSales.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
        }
    }

    private void dataGridSales_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
            dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH");
            dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("C2");
            dataGridSales.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(Double);
        }
    }

    //Double click on a cell to edit
    private void dataGridSales_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            dataGridSales.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this winform or wpf?

Comment: @Alander in winform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not specifying the culture on which the formatter should format. This should solve your problem.

```
private void dataGridSales_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
            dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle
                                    .FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("c");

    }
}
```

Note that you should replace "en-US" with the [culture code/index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) of your desired currency.

Edit:

You should also try to add the following code to a method that is run prior to data load:

```
dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("c");
dataGridSales.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(Double);
```

Comment: I've tested it and it should work, can you share all the events for  `dataGridSales` ?


Edit: can you try applying this code to the Form_Load method, or any equivilent method (prior to loading data into the grid view)?

`dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

                dataGridSales.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = String.Format("c");

                dataGridSales.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(Double);`

Comment: I have set the column defaultstyle to the picture above, also posted all dataGridSales events. Still the format isn't applied after editting.

Comment: I have added the 2nd set of code to my form load and it is now working. Thanks

Comment: @Jepher glad it helped. my pleasure.